# Displaying wordpress page full contents

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Here is [LINK](https://website.com/tempp/) I am working on it. The `About Us` section is not displaying full contents and showing more button to go to next page whereas I want to show full contents of `About Us` page instead of short summary.

I checked a lot but not found any option in the theme to fix it

**UPDATE:**
I found this in (page-template/custom-home-page.php)

```
<?php  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <hr>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="more-btn">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('MORE','vw-one-page'); ?></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>"/>
          </div> 
        </div>
      <?php $i++; endwhile; 
      wp_reset_postdata();?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="no-postfound"></div>
    <?php endif;
    endif;?>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Best regards

Comment: nothing wrong with your theme i have test the theme locally and it works fine https://prnt.sc/nzh5cl 
are you sure you are setting your pages yuo as pages because i can see your services and product sections are actually posts not pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code inside your theme with high probability.
Try to search inside theme files "/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name", something like that:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7">
<h3>About Us</h3> <!-- Or <?php the_title(); ?> -->
<hr>
<?php the_exerpt(); ?>
    <div class="more-btn">
      <a href="<https://yoursite/tempp/index.php/about-us/>">MORE</a> <!-- Or something like <?php the_permalink( ... ) ?> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an example. After all, I can't know how it is done in  your theme.

Then `<?php the_exerpt(); ?>` change to `<?php the_content(); ?>`. and remove or hide:

```
<div class="more-btn">
    ...
</div>
```

But if this is not your personal WordPress theme, then it is better to do through [Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: In which file I make this changes? I am using [VW One Page Pro](https://www.vwthemesdemo.com/docs/free-vw-one-page/) theme

Comment: please remove domain name from your post

Comment: @user987376746090 You update question with file content.php there is `<div class="box-image col-lg-6 col-md-6">`, but your about txt is inside div `<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7">`. Try to search files with `col-lg-8 col-md-7`. First look at page.php.

Comment: @user987376746090 use any program that can search text inside theme folder files like Sublime Text or Double Commander

Comment: I replaced the updated text as I found `col-lg-8 col-md-7` in template folder. I copy pasted its section. Please check